# Is pre-order traversal a depth-first method?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

Is pre-order traversal a depth-first algorithm?  I'm using it in my search below.I have included the code below.

```
public bool DFS1(int value, BSTNode root)
{    // Pre-order search

    if (root == null)
        return false;

    if (root.data == value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("found");
        return true;
    }

    DFS1(value, root.left); //vist the left node
    return DFS1(value, root.right); // vist the right node.
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the result from the left recursion. You don't need the right search if the left succeeds.

Comment: @A.Sarid  The basic issue is a duplicate.  However OP has issues in the dual recursion to solve that (IMHO) warrant keeping this question open.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is depth-first: you will complete the left sub-tree completely before you look at the original root's right node.  However, you need to consider the result from that left search.  At the moment, this will return **true** iff the rightmost node has the target value.

```
return DFS1(value, root.left) or
       DFS1(value, root.right)
```

Most compilers will optimize this (short-circuit), so that if the left side returns **true**, the right will not execute.  If not, you can write it yourself:

```
if (DFS1(value, root.left))
    return true;
else
    return DFS1(value, root.right);
```

Comment: @Prune- Good catch. I didn't know how to return after the recursive two calls since" return false" at the end code was returning incorrect value. Is there another way of returning without using the OR condition?

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Please remember to accept your favourite answer so Stack Overflow can properly retire the question.